# Kibana is installed and running but cannot access localhost:5601

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If I run `ps aux | grep kibana`

It shows:

`kibana   14993 36.7  7.8 1382596 312372 ?      Ssl  14:24   0:10 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings --max-http-header-size=65536 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

If I run `sudo systemctl status kibana.service`

It shows:

```
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-27 14:24:06 CST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 14993 (node)
    Tasks: 11 (limit: 4574)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─14993 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings --max-http-header-size=65536 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /

Feb 27 14:24:06 aero systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
```

But if I run nmap:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
631/tcp   open  ipp
1080/tcp  open  socks
6001/tcp  open  X11:1
9200/tcp  open  wap-wsp
65000/tcp open  unknown
```

Here is my `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
#server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "user"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
#i18n.locale: "en"
```

Of course, I could manually start Kibana with:

`sudo /usr/share/kibana/node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

netstat -an | grep 5601

to see which host:port Kibana has binded to.

Comment: It doesn't bind to any port.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when configuring SSL for ELK stack and securely connecting Kibana with Elastic Search.
I followed the steps here for 8.x ELK version

https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash

The error occurred when launching kibana at port 5601 from its public-facing Url for the first time. However, when I refreshed the browser, it prompted for a login/password, and I could load Kibana successfully at port 5601 like http://<X.X.X.X>:5601

Answer (score 0):

You may check the process log to get more details on if there are any warnings or errors. Based on your config file, I don't see the definition of ElasticSearch port, only this:

```
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

You will need to make sure elastic search is accessible at localhost:9200, and uncomment this line.